# moderncv - trying to remove that bullet point and create more space

Tags: formatting, moderncv

I'm very new to LaTex and even more to `moderncv`

I'm trying to do two things

1. removing that bullet point just before my email

[image]

2. Put more space after `programmations` or `Outils de marketing digital`

[image]

I read that I need to amend `moderncvstylecasual.sty` but I'm unsure.

Any tips are more than welcomed as I'm struggling.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to the first question. Line 32 in moderncvstylecasual.sty

```
%   footer symbol used to separate footer elements
\newcommand*{\footersymbol}{%
    {~~~{\rmfamily\textbullet}~~~}
```

Simply put

```
\newcommand*{\footersymbol}{%
    {~~~{}~~~}}
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

For the second question you might set the hintscolumnwidth(in your document, just after the documentclass):

```
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.175\textwidth}
```

to something you think fits better. For example 4cm:

```
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{4cm}
```

Comment: Hi @BenjaminH, thanks. Your advice does the trick. Cheers.